# Dot notation in href replacing entire URL path

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, href

I am working on an AngularJS web application where I need to use an href in the template to launch a child state. Long story, but href is my only option for now (not alternatives like $state.go() or ui-sref directives, etc.).

Basically I'm trying to launch a child state (a modal window) that is routed to my current state (parent). An example *current* URL from which the link can be clicked is

```
localhost:3000/#/contact/aboutus
```

This is not the only possible parenting state throughout the app, though, so I need the initial part of the path to remain dynamic. Let's say I'm trying to launch a "directory" modal window from this page, though, that corresponds to the following URL:

```
localhost:3000/#/contact/aboutus/directory
```

I would expect this to be possible with the following code that I have:

```
<div class="internal-margin">
    <a href="./directory">
        <span ng-bind-html="'{{link.label | translate}}'"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Notice the href="./directory". I am trying to use this dot notation in order to append to the existing URL path. When I click the link on the page, however, it directs me to the URL:

```
localhost:3000/directory
```

The entire path is replaced and this URL is a 404. Why is this happening? Does the problem lie deeper in how the ui routing is taking place, or am I completely missing something?

Comment: Can we know how `ui-sref` would not work?

Comment: Also, `./directory` _is_ the right way to append the path to the existing path

Comment: @PankajParkar please see my comment below in reply to your answer I understand this is correct way but it is not working in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation is not taking into account that you are using hash based routing

`./directory` will not append to the url hash, and has no hash in it

When writing the href manually it would have to be:

```
<a href="#/contact/aboutus/directory">
```

There is no shorthand for this